do-release-upgrade with a local apt repo
Edit
I tried with this command on Ansible:
- name: Run do-release-upgrade
  ansible.builtin.command: /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive

It simply just quits when I do that.
I tested it out via SSH without the frontend:
This session appears to be running under ssh. It is not recommended
to perform a upgrade over ssh currently because in case of failure it
is harder to recover.

If you continue, an additional ssh daemon will be started at port
'1022'.
Do you want to continue?

Continue [yN] y

Starting additional sshd

To make recovery in case of failure easier, an additional sshd will
be started on port '1022'. If anything goes wrong with the running
ssh, you can still connect to the additional one.
If you run a firewall, you may need to temporarily open this port. As
this is potentially dangerous it's not done automatically. You can
open the port with e.g.:
'iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1022 -j ACCEPT'

To continue please press [ENTER]

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://<mirrored local repo>/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit http://<mirrored local repo>/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit http://<mirrored local repo>/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit http://<mirrored local repo>/DeAdBCiUYInHcSTy/pcoip-client/deb/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit http://<mirrored local repo>/pitchblack stable InRelease
Hit http://<mirrored local repo>/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
none
None

Updating repository information

No valid mirror found

While scanning your repository information no mirror entry for the
upgrade was found. This can happen if you run an internal mirror or
if the mirror information is out of date.

Do you want to rewrite your 'sources.list' file anyway? If you choose
'Yes' here it will update all 'focal' to 'jammy' entries.
If you select 'No' the upgrade will cancel.

I suspect they're stopping at the SSH question or the mirror question.

Original question
I have Ubuntu 20.04 systems at my workplace, and I want to do an do-relelase-upgrade but it will only use my local apt repo.  I'm currently debating on upgrading 22.04 or jumping straight to 24.04.
How would I make sure that it won't use the official Ubuntu repo and only local apt mirror, including custom repos?
My current plan is to do an Ansible task that will run do-release-upgrade, but I'm looking for a way to make sure it doesn't use the official repos.  I did debate on just changing all instances of "focal" and change it to "jammy" or "noble", but I have some reservations on that as I'm jumping from one LTS to another.

Keep in mind do-release-upgrade drops third party APT sources if you have any. If you have any PPAs installed and you do not want to use during the upgrade, you need to upgrade manually by changing APT sources.

Yes, I'm aware.  I tested it out without the non-interactive frontend and it works.
